# Why is my F3 key not working when running Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Just yesterday, I bought a laptop and I set it up. Everything works and it's great, but, the F3 key isn't working on Minecraft. Outside of Minecraft, the F3 key is responsive (it brightens the screen), but just not in Minecraft. If you're wondering, I'm using a **Windows 8 HP Pavilion laptop**. Remember, I just got this laptop yesterday, so don't go saying my keys are bad or something.

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Is the F3 key listed in the keybindings menu?

Comment: Almost guaranteed, it's a function binding.  Find the Fn key, hold it down, and then hit F3.

Comment: Thanks! How could I be so dumb not to think that?! Anyway, It worked and now I don't have to be scouting for diamonds at level 67 or something. :D

Answer (score 2):

To explain what @Frank said in more detail: on some computers (especially laptops) there is an extra function for each F-key.  In your case, screen brightness for F3.  Usually there is a key labeled Fn or F-lock somewhere near that row.  You might have to hold it, you might have to toggle it, but it should change the mode of your F3 key between "brightness mode" and actually sending the F3 signal to the program.

Comment: I noticed you figured it out, just thought I'd explain it in more detail for anyone who can't :)